# Is there any way to implement algorithm using ONLY regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex

I have string with only `+` and `-`, plus increases some variable, minus respectively decreases it. I should check if variable will be less than 0 or greater than N during processing any symbol of input string.

For example I have input:

```
N = 10
string = "+++++++++---+-+-+"
```

Output:

```
True
```

Input:

```
N = 3
string = "+-+-+-++-+++--"
```

Output:

```
False
```

Python solution is:

```
def check(string, N):
    accumulator = 0
    for ch in string:
        if ch == '+':
            accumulator += 1
        elif ch == '-':
            accumulator -= 1
        if accumulator < 0 or accumulator > N:
            return False
     return True
```

But I need to implement this using ONLY regular expressions, like this:

```
def check(string, N):
    regex = r'^$'  # <-- regex is here
    return bool(re.match(regex, string))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `string.count("+") - string.count("-")` would be better... good luck with pure regex on that one.

Comment: I would start by designing a *Finite State Machine*, and then turn that into a regex.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, my solution with accumulator is even better, but as I mentioned I can't use it

Comment: @devalone: why don't you aim to do the homework yourself first? What regexes did you try? Why it did not work?

Comment: This clearly fails at the "practical" part of the "practical, answerable" criteria from https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Anyone trying to find a *practical* solution wouldn't attempt to use a regex where it isn't the right tool for the job.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I don't have ideas how to create variable or something working like variables in regex

Comment: This isn't a [regular language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language), so the simple regex features aren't going to cut it. You'll need the more advanced stuff.

Comment: (and, to be clear, "the more advanced stuff" is generally the set of functionality that requires backtracking regex implementations -- so it's stuff you *really* shouldn't use in real-world applications if performance and predictability are in any way important; see also https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html).

Comment: ...but no, there are no variables, and there are no analogues to variables, so you can't just port your algorithm. Instead, you need to find a regex that matches any string where (say) any `-` can't be matched with a preceding `+`.

Comment: @user2357112: it is not a regular language in case `n` is not known in advance. But if `n` is known, one can construct a FSM and thus a regex to process it.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Yeah, I didn't see the "or greater than N" part when I wrote my first comment. Wondering whether to delete it, actually. If you treat the N input as part of the language (with some appropriate encoding), it's still not regular, but treating N as selecting from a family of languages (which seems more natural), each of those languages are regular.